# BizTalk Server without administrative rights

Tags: windows-7, biztalk, biztalk-2010, admin-rights

I want to run BizTalk server 2010 on windows 7. Problem is my company’s management does not want to give local administrator rights to developers. Can I perform BizTalk operations (like start/stop/create/ delete host and host instances, publish website on IIS, deploy services, import/export MSI and bindings, create SSO and BRE entries, etc) without local administrator rights.

I also need to work on ESB toolkit.

I want to confirm that, due to the absence of local administrator rights, would I stuck or be in trouble at any stage of BizTalk service live cycle ? and is there any way around to overcome those issues ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best answer: Can they provision a VM of Windows Server 2008 R2 for you where you can be a local Administrator and run BizTalk Server?  Even the most security conscious environments I've been in allow this.

To address your specific question: No, you don't need to have local Administrator, but...there are a number of tasks during BizTalk DEV that require a very high level of privilege on the system, such as creating and managing Services, deploying/installing applications, managing the Global Assemble Cache and probably a few more.

So, by the time you get all the system rights to do these, you're pretty close to being a local Administrator anyway.

Either way, a VM is still the preferable option.  Technically, it doesn't even have to be joined to a Domain so you'd really be in a sandbox.

Comment: I agree with boatseller, this is your best option. Microsoft Azure might even be a good option for you to host your development machine.